# How to check with jQuery if any form is submitted?

Tags: jquery, forms, onsubmit

I have a page with a lot of forms, and the user is going to pick something on that page. When the user does, I need to place that element somewhere else, much like a shopping cart really. But I can't seem to get more than the first form on the page to actually work as intended.
I've tried multiple things:

1. Give all forms the same ID, which only caused the first form to act as I wanted, giving me the data of that form.
2. Give them all the same ID again, this time appending a unique identifier to the ID, but of course, then my jQuery `$('#something')` doesn't catch it since it doesn't match.

So I am thinking how I would go about this. I need to only recieve the data from the submitted form on the page. And as mentioned, I could give them all a prefix of some sort, like I have now, but then I don't know how to match it.

Help would be greatly appriciated!

Some code as requested (only an example to show what I mean, of course):

The HTML:

```
<form id="something-0"><input type="hidden" value="0"><input type="submit"></form>
<form id="something-1"><input type="hidden" value="1"><input type="submit"></form>
```

The jQuery:

```
$("#something-%").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#some-span").html(data);
});
```

I want the #something-% to accept anything that comes after the "-", I hope you understand.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Can we get a fiddle example?

Comment: code would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You don't really need the same id on all forms - that is BAD practice (and will probably break your code). Instead, keep a global array or something which keeps track of which form has been submitted. If you are using jquery, you can easily set that flag from the `submit` event capture.

Comment: ID's must be unique.  Have you tried $('form').[submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As a general answer, to classify a group of elements, use the `class` attribute, giving each element the same class name.  You can then select elements by that class.  An element can have more than one class.

```
$(".something");
```

If you must use id, you can use an attribute selector:

```
$("[id^='something']");  // all elements with an id beginning with 'something'
$("[id$='something']");  // all elements with an id ending with 'something'
```

For this specific question, since you want to act on any form within the page, the simplest choice would be to use the element name selector:

```
$("form");
```

Regardless of the selector, you can identify which form was submitted by referencing `this` within the `submit()` handler:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formId = this.id;  // "this" is a reference to the submitted form
});
```

Comment: Thanks it helps me.

Answer (score 10):

You can catch all forms by using the selector 'form', e.g.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  var theForm = $(this);
  var formID = theForm.attr("id");
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Did you forget quotes?  `$("form")`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
   $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if (e.result == true) {
       alert("This form was submitted!")
     }
   });
```

Comment: Not that preventDefault is missing the parenthesises to make it a function `e.preventDefault()`